# Problem with my Octave code (unsteady heat equation with FEM)

Tags: finite-element, fluid-dynamics, octave, heat-transfer

I want help with my Octave code regarding the unsteady heat equation.

My geometry and mesh are generated with FreeFEM++, so there is no problem with that (I tried it with the steady problem with no for loop and it worked just fine).

But when I introduce the for loop to iterate with the time step and try to visualize the results at multiple steps, the results remain the same for the entire loop with no change in figures or in Temperature data.

I tried varying the time step, the maximum number of iterations, the source term, and alpha (implicit/explicit Euler and Crank-Nicolson)

[image: the formula I used]

[image: Results]
Here is the script :

```
% Visual aspects
set(0,'defaultAxesFontSize',20);
set(0,'defaultAxesLineWidth',2);

% Physical parameters
kappa=0.005;
amplitude_s=0.0; % 0.0
Thole=5;
Tborder=2;
Tcolormap=[2 5];

% Read the informations from the geometry
x=readarray('x.dat');
y=readarray('y.dat');
mesh_info=load('meshinfo.dat');

% Read matrices from the Finite Element Formulation
% Read mass matrix
M=readmat('M.dat');
[n,m]=size(M);
%pcolor(M);
%
K=readmat('K.dat');
%
% Get the position of the Dirichlet masks
BC_Dir_hole=readarray('BCdir5.dat');
ii_Dir_hole=find(abs(BC_Dir_hole)>0);
BC_Dir_borders=readarray('BCdir1234.dat');
ii_Dir_borders=find(abs(BC_Dir_borders)>0);
BC_Dir=readarray('BCdir.dat');
ii_int=find(BC_Dir==0);
%
% Build corresponding matrices
T=zeros(n,1);
alpha=0;
%alpha=1
%alpha=1/2
N=100;
delta_t=0.001;
A=1/delta_t*M+alpha*kappa*K;
Ared=A(ii_int,ii_int);
s=amplitude_s*ones(n,1);
s_new=s;
B=(1/delta_t*M-(1-alpha)*kappa*K)*T+M*(alpha*s_new+(1-alpha)*s);
% SOLVE
Td=zeros(n,1);
Td(ii_Dir_hole)=Thole;
Td(ii_Dir_borders)=Tborder;
%
for nt=1:N
C=B-A*Td;
Cred=C(ii_int);
Tred=Ared\Cred;
%
T=Td;
T(ii_int)=Tred;
%
if mod(nt,10)==0;
    FIG=visu_2D(x,y,mesh_info,T,'none','off');
    %FIG=visu_2D_visibility(x,y,mesh_info,T,'none','on');
     caxis(Tcolormap);
     %
     savename=['PIC/PIC_' sprintf('%05d',not)];
     print(FIG,'-r200','-djpg',savename);
     close all;
  end
 endfor
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you write down the differential equations, boundary and initial conditions for your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading quickly through your code, it seems that you never update B. So the term $T^n$ of the previous step remains unchanged, hence you are effectively computing the same step over and over again...

There might be other issues but I cannot test the code at the moment.

Comment: Indeed, how did I miss that! a simple copy paste of the formula inside the loop did the trick.

Comment: Thanks you so much

Comment: @mibo27 You're welcome. Can you accept the answer so that this question is marked as "resolved" ?